# issue passing HTML to Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an issue passing a value into an ajax request.

In the success section of the request, the following HTML should be passed to the request (at the moment it is "Quality Control")

```
<p id ="LocationName">@JobTracker.Helpers.GetIP.LocationIPAssign()</p>
```

However, the location in the combobox never changes to Quality Control. I removed the get element and tried just hard-coding "Quality Control" into the var LocationName and it works fine. Maybe im passing the value the wrong way?

Here is the ajax request. Also the helper is displaying the location properly as it is displayed in the top corner throughout the MVC application, i thought it was due to spelling ha

```
$('#qr-number').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: '/CameraInfo/Edit',
        data: {
            ID: $('#qr-number').val()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#JobEdit').html(response);
            var locationName = $('#LocationName').val();
            //Changes DropDownList to value of "LocationName"
            $("#Location option:contains(" + locationName + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
        },
        error: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText != "") {
                alert(response.responseText);
                alert("Some thing wrong..");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's because `LocationName` is a paragraph and not a `select`. Edit your question and post the `HTML` inside of `<p id ="LocationName">...</p>`

Comment: `<p>` doesn't have a value-attribute, val() will not return anything. Use html() or text() instead

Comment: thanks guys! both of these worked! i didnt know about the text() attribute, thanks again